# Stripped screw - won’t budge tub faucet trim screw

Tags: faucet

I have a leaky tub faucet, and The screw is stripped and also won’t budge. I’ve tried a bunch of different methods to get it out-  two different lubricants, screw extractors, vise grips, cutting a small hole for a flat head with a Dremel, hitting the screwdriver with a hammer to loosen it, and nothing works.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I have had really good luck with a tool called "vampliers," even when everything else failed.

Answer (score 1):

That actually kinda looks like an ECX (combination) screw, not a Phillips head...have you tried an ECX driver?  Of course, you may have bunged it up with all your efforts.

[image]

Also, have you tried a penetrant, like AeroKroil?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these

1. Sometimes, tightening it a bit allows it to turn the other way
2. Use a screw extractor with the drill in reverse,
3. Carefully drill out the head of the screw, so you can remove the faucet.